# GDScan.exe causing massive CPU load

Tags: cpu-usage, gdata

Yesterday when I was doing something on a computer, all of the sudden I started experiencing massive slowdown of machine. First time I just restarted computer, but when it happened again, I looked at the task manager. At first glance every process was using 1-2% of CPU, but when I showed processes opened by all users, I saw a process called GDScan.exe (started by user SYSTEM) which used up to 99% of CPU! First what I tried to do is forcing the process to quit, but I couldn't do it (access denied). Since then it eventually happens every time I start my system, maybe an hour or so after turning on. GDScan.exe procees usually works on 1% of CPU at most.

I wanted to ask if there is any way of preventing such massive CPU load by this process? And if it happens, can I somehow end it?

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

G Data version: 25.0.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It's just.. your scan of GData (very gourmand) ! Restarting doesn't solve. You just need to stop the scan cliking right on the icon (right bottom) or simply wait the scan finish ! You can plan the scan.